# Dynamic or fixed options?

Tags: php, oop, class, security

I am wondering what method is considered best practice, and why?

Having the function so it attempts to grab whatever is passed in.

```
class Test{

    private $first = 'first';
    private $second = 'second';

    public function data($what){
        return $this->{strtolower($what)};
    }

}
```

or having a fixed set of options:

```
class Test{

    private $first = 'first';
    private $second = 'second';

    public function data($what){
        switch(strtolower($what)){
            case 'first':
                $value = $this->first;
                break;
            case 'second':
                $value = $this->second;
                break;
            default:
                $value = null;
        }
        return $value;
    }

}
```

Using the first option means that I don't need to alter the function every time I add a new member to the class, but it also means that I can no longer have `private` class members.

Using the second options means I need to alter the function every time I add a new member, but it means that I can make sure nothing is read that shouldn't be.

With the first method if I want to add extra processing to particular members I can just add an if statement for those members.

With the second method I can do the processing inside the case statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the code needs to know what to extrapolate from an object Dynamic is not better, being specific is not being sloppy with writing code. It means that you have used you brains to think about the consequences of that action.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just go with the first one and take advantage of the magic method [`__get()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get).

```
class Test {

    private $first = 'first';
    private $second = 'second';

    public function data($what){
        return $this->{strtolower($what)};
    }

    public function __get($what){
        // This method is called whenever you're trying to access an inaccessible property.
        return null;
    }
}

$Test = new Test();
var_dump($Test->data('first')); // string: 'first'
var_dump($Test->data('abcde')); // null
```

Of course, you can also go with some other alternative, like defining an array of which properties can be retrieved from the function. Then, when in your `data()` function, just check to see if the requested property is retrievable. Otherwise return null

```
class Test {
    private $first = 'first';
    private $second = 'second';
    private $retrievable = array('first', 'second');

    public function data($what)
    {
        if (in_array($what, $this->retrievable))
        {
            return $this->{strtolower($what)};
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This way, you don't have to modify your code, just edit the array of retrievable items.